# Shell Command to copy a directory to another location

Tags: php, bash, shell

In my web application I have to copy a directory and all its contents to another location.
I want to use `shell_exec` function of PHP. But I can't find the command for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
cp -r source dest
```

Copies source and all contents of source inside dest.

Answer (score 3):

Define "location" more precisely. In any event:

- if the directory is local: `cp -r sourcedir destdir`;
- if it is remote, using scp: `scp -r sourcedir user@targetmachine:destdir`

Answer (score 2):

The PHP manual has a page for the [`copy` function](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) where you can find a many recipes for recursive directory copy. Here is an adapted recipe:

```
function recurse_copy($srcdir, $dstdir) {
    $dir = opendir($srcdir);
    @mkdir($dstdir);
    while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
        if ($file != '.'  && $file != '..') {
            $src = $srcdir . '/' . $file;
            $dst = $dstdir . '/' . $file;
            if (is_dir($src)) { 
                recurse_copy($src, $dst); 
            } else { 
                copy($src, $dst); 
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
}
```